# How to install the TikZ library 'quotes'

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, miktex, installing

I need to use the TikZ library `quotes`. I have MiKTeX Version 2.9 but **no admin privileges**, so I cannot update TikZ.

In my current version I cannot use this library since it it not installed. Is there a way to easily add (only this) library so that I can use it? For example by adding a file to MiKTeX/tex/generic or somewhere else?

Comment: please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: Note that [miktex 2.9 has been out for over 6 years](https://miktex.org/releases) but is updated under the same version number so yours could well be hopelessly out of date. What version number/date do you get if you type `pdftex \bye` from the commandline? (I'm on Tex Live so can't compare exactly).

Answer (score 2):

The `quote` library for TikZ can be downloaded from [this link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex). Download the file, and then copy it to

```
TEXMF/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries
```

where `TEXMF` is your TeX directory.

It's worth noting, however, that this file is included by default as a part of PGF/TikZ, and seems to have been since at least 2014. This suggests that your TikZ distribution is hopelessly out of date, in which case you should speak to your system administrator.

Comment: "your TeX directory" is a bit vage. It is *not*  a good idea to put such files in the main texmf tree of miktex.  It is better to create a local texmf tree.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree that this isn't a good idea, but since OP is using a years-out-of-date distribution to which he doesn't have administrator access, creating a local `texmf` tree is out of the question.